# Is there a faster way to run this Powershell search?

Tags: powershell

I'm searching my music library for songs that have a title matching one extracted from a filename. The resulting search is terribly slow.

```
ls -Path "C:\Music\New Tracks" | foreach -Process { dir -r -i *.mp3 -Path C:\Music\* | Select-String ([regex]'^.+ - (?<SongTitle>.*)\.mp3$').match($_.Name).Groups[1].Value }
```

Is there a much faster way to script it?

A sample filename to give the pattern is `Coldplay Feat Rihanna - Princess Of China.mp3`

Comment: Is this slow even for 1 file in *New tracks* folder?

Comment: Is it your intent to search the binary MP3 files using Select-String for an embedded filename?

Comment: @Keith, the intent is to locate the title string in the binary mp3 file.

Comment: Rather than do a search of a rather large file, you could try search by the file attributes (title, etc) instead: http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2005/12/10/msh-get-extended-properties-of-a-file/  Not sure if it would be faster though.

Comment: That's a very helpful article. I'll use the Title attribute for the search

Comment: You might be interested in today's [Hey!, Scripting Guy](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/06/25/build-a-query-to-search-the-windows-index-from-powershell.aspx) blog about using PowerShell to search the Windows index.

Comment: @KeithHill I ended up using Taglib-Sharp to extract the Song Title since the Windows Shell used in your article does not have support for id3 tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running the C:\Music* listing multiple times - once for each Name in `New Tracks`.  I would optimize this a bit e.g.:

```
$pattern = '^.+ - (?<SongTitle>.*)\.mp3$'
$names = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Music\New Tracks' | 
             Foreach { if ($_.Name -match $pattern) {$matches.SongTitle} }
Get-ChildItem C:\Music -r *.mp3 | 
    Where {$filename = $_.Name; $names | Where {$filename -match $_}}
```

This assumes you have fewer names in New Tracks than MP3 files which seems logical

Comment: agreed with the idea of optimizing. So you're getting all the SongTitles first and then using that to find a match in the music files. Question is, how does the script know to go through all SongTitles for each $filename?

Comment: Each MP3 is piped into a Where-Object cmdlet.  Inside that cmdlet's scriptblock I stash the MP3 filename in $filename, then I start another pipeline and run each found title ($names) into another Where-Object cmdlet that checks to see if any of those names match the current MP3 filename.